# Test AdMob banner adViewWillPresentScreen method without creating false ad impressions

Tags: ios, admob

I've implemented AdMob in to my application, but I'd like to ensure that the logic in the `adViewWillPresentScreen:` and `adViewDidDismissScreen:` methods are correct.

I have added my device's ID as a test device, so that I am only displayed test adverts. However, when I tap on the test advert, I am taken directly out of the app, rather than a screen (such as the App Store) being displayed. This means that the above methods are not being fired, and I am unsure how to test them without removing my device from the array of test devices and creating a false impression by tapping on one of my own ads - potentially repeatably while debugging.

Code creating banner:

```
let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: size)
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.adUnitID = "<redacted>"
bannerView.rootViewController = rootViewController
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [
    kGADSimulatorID,
    "<redacted>" // Test device
]
bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```

I have also tried an example adUnitID (`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`), which even when my device is not in the array of test devices displayed the example advert.

Comment: When using the example AdUnitID I get the [example advert](https://imgur.com/QHhBcI0). Tapping this advert takes me out of the app, rather than displaying a modal screen, which would trigger the `adViewWillPresentScreen:` method. I am looking for a way to load a test advert which shows a modal screen when tapped.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I am having the exact same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. I also posted on the admob forums but don't recall getting a useful reply.